# function fputcsv. The file is empty

Tags: php

This is a part of my code. Can someone tell me why this doesn't work. The file is empty..

```
$employees = crb_get_employees_started_in_date_range( $start_date, $end_date 
);
$test = ['test', 'test', 'test' ];
$file = fopen( CRB_THEME_DIR . 'employees.csv', 'a');

foreach ( $employees as $employee ) {
    fputcsv( CRB_THEME_DIR . 'employees.csv', $test );
}

fclose( $file );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fputcsv()` parameter 1 is the file handle returned by `fopen()` ( documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

```
fputcsv( CRB_THEME_DIR . 'employees.csv', $test );
```

should be

```
fputcsv( $file, $test );
```

I'm assuming that `$test` was just something to check your output.